# Convert a string tree to array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got objects with an id as a string. Each object can be the child of another object. Relations can be guessed from IDs. For exemple:

```
[
  { id: '1:2:6', ids: ['1', '2', '6'] },
  { id: '1:4', ids: ['1', '4'] },
  { id: '1', ids: ['1'] },
  { id: '1:2', ids: ['1', '2'] },
]
```

In this exemple, root object is `id: 1`, which has 2 childrens `id: 1:2` and `id: 1:4`. Finaly, `id: 1:2` has a children `id: 1:2:6`.

I would like to convert this array to another array where childrens are embeded into parents, so the previous array would result in:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    children: [
      {
        id: '1:2',
        children: [
          { id: '1:2:6', children: [] }
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '1:4',
        children: [],
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I can use ES6. I tried for hours to find a solution using all sort of loops but I can't figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you tried so we can help you get it working.

Comment: is 'ids' part of the actual object or is it only for show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the objects and reduce `ids` by looking for an object at the actual level. If not found create a new object. Then return the children.

```js
var data = [{ id: '1:2:6', ids: ['1', '2', '6'] }, { id: '1:4', ids: ['1', '4'] }, { id: '1', ids: ['1'] }, { id: '1:2', ids: ['1', '2'] }],
    tree = data.reduce((r, { ids }) => {
        ids.reduce((t, _, i, a) => {
            var id = a.slice(0, i + 1).join(':'),
                temp = t.find(o => o.id === id);
            
            if (!temp) t.push(temp = { id, children: [] });
            return temp.children;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, I guess we don't have the same brain. Awesome algorithme. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the iterative approach is more readable so maybe provided solution will help you understand how it is done (though it is lightly inspired by Nina's answer)

So what we do is iterate over all objects in the list.
Initially, for each object, we set the current nodeList as the final tree. And we iterate over the length of ids.

First, we create the id form the list of ids by dividing the `ids` array into incrementally larger chunks with `slice` (['1'], ['1','2'], ['1', '2', '6') and concatenate to a string with `:`. So we get 1, 1:2, 1:2:6 ids for the first item.

Next, we find a node in `currentNodelist` by previously constructed id. If we cannot find the node that means we have not added it yet so we need to create and add it (If we find it then we don't need to do add it).

In the next step, we need to go deeper into the tree so we assign the currently created(or the one that we found) node's children as `currentNodelist`. With this, we traverse the tree deeper by provided ids.

```
let objs = [
  { id: '1:2:6', ids: ['1', '2', '6'] },
  { id: '1:4', ids: ['1', '4'] },
  { id: '1', ids: ['1'] },
  { id: '1:2', ids: ['1', '2'] },
];

let tree = [];
for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
  let obj = objs[i];

  let currentNodeList = tree;
  for (let j = 0; j < obj.ids.length; j++) {
    let id = obj.ids.slice(0, j + 1).join(':');
    let currentNode = currentNodeList.find((node) => node.id === id);

    if (!currentNode) {
      currentNode = {id, children: []};
      currentNodeList.push(currentNode);
    } 

    currentNodeList = currentNode.children;
  }
}

console.log(tree);
```

I created a simple gif that shows what is happening in the first 2 iterations. The arrow is pointing to `currentListNode`.

[image]

Comment: Just for the time you should have spent on this answer I should be able to select this as an alternative accepted answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :) (it was fun working on this question )

Answer (score 0):

Figure out your algorithm "on paper" first. Let's start with an empty tree and take the first entry: 
[1, 2, 6].

1. Node 1: add 1 to the tree - it's now the root and the last visited node.
2. Node 2: add child 2 to node 1.
3. Node 6: add child 6 to node 2.

When processing the next entry, [1, 4], 1 is already in the tree - just add 4 to it.

When processing the last entry, [1, 2], be mindful that 2 is also already in the tree.

P.S. It's "children" not "childs".

Comment: I replace childs by children haha thanks, sorry for my bad english. I did tried on paper first but could not find a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building a tree using recursive algorithms

```
var jsonTree = [{ id: '1:2:6', ids: ['1', '2', '6'] },{ id: '1:4', ids: ['1', '4'] },{ id: '1', ids: ['1'] },{ id: '1:2', ids: ['1', '2'] },]

var newJsonTree = [];
var currentElement = {id: '1',childs: []}
newJsonTree.push(currentElement)

function buildTree(jsonTree, currentElement){
    for(var i=0;i<jsonTree.length;i++){
        var parent = jsonTree[i];
        for(var j=0;j<jsonTree.length;j++){
            var child = jsonTree[j];
            if(child['visited'] != true && child['id'] != currentElement['id'] && child['id'].indexOf(currentElement['id']) == 0 ){
                if(child['id'].split(":").length == currentElement['id'].split(":").length+1){
                    var newElement = {}
                    newElement['id'] = child['id'];
                    newElement['childs'] = [];
                    currentElement['childs'].push(newElement);
                    child['visited'] = true;
                    buildTree(jsonTree, newElement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

buildTree(jsonTree, currentElement);
document.write(JSON.stringify(newJsonTree));
```

result:

[{"id":"1","childs":[{"id":"1:4","childs":[]},{"id":"1:2","childs":[{"id":"1:2:6","childs":[]}]}]}]